# Was Saladin Agnostic?

Tags: crusades, 12th-century, saladin

In the movie "Kingdom of Heaven", Saladin was portrayed as somewhat agnostic. He has been portrayed this way in literature as well, if I recall correctly.

Is there a basis to this?

Comment: Why was the tag seljuk-turks added? As far as I know Saladin was Kurd not Turk.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Can we think of any reason why a major American Holywood motion picture would wish to distance it's hero from Islam?

Most of his portrayal in 'literature' is from Walter Scott and the Victorians which tells you a  lot more about their attitudes to themselves and what they saw as important values than it does about an actual medieval Islamic ruler